# Why does Steam run on startup despite my preference to the contrary?

Tags: steam

I have Steam installed on my Mac, and when I look in the preferences, I can clearly see that it is configured **not** to launch on startup (see screenshot):

[image: Don't run Steam when my computer starts]

Despite this, Steam is still launching every time my computer starts!

Is there another setting somewhere I have to change? Could there be something else starting Steam?

Why does Steam run on startup despite my preference to the contrary?

Comment: Steam may be set up to auto-start in a way it does not recognize itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go the Apple menu and choose “System Preferences”, then go to “Users & Groups”
2. Select the user that is active in OS X, then choose the “Login Items” tab.
3. Select “Steam” from this list and then hit the Delete key on the keyboard to remove steam from the automatic launch on login list.

Comment: Aha, this looks very promising! I also found some other stuff there I am happy to remove :) I'll come back here and mark this as the accepted answer next time I restart my computer and see it working :)